Makefile - How to run additional commands in a target based on exit code of a previous command
I am trying to leverage make to run some jobs in parallel by generating a Makefile that looks like this:
test_all: test_1 test_2 test_3

test_1:
    @echo "Starting test 1"
    @run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1
    # if run_some_job passed, print "Test 1 passed", else print "Test 1 failed"
    
test_2:
    @echo "Starting test 2"
    @run_some_job > test_2.log 2>&1
    # if run_some_job passed, print "Test 2 passed", else print "Test 2 failed"

test_3:
    @echo "Starting test 3"
    @run_some_job > test_3.log 2>&1
    # if run_some_job passed, print "Test 3 passed", else print "Test 3 failed"

I will invoke using make -j10 so that all of these run in parallel, capturing their stdout+stderr in individual log files.
Question: How can I do the thing I want to in that comment above? Note that here I am just doing a print, but in reality I may want to do custom things in the next command based on whether the previous command passed or failed.
if run_some_job passed, print "Test N passed", else print "Test N failed"



# if run_some_job passed, print "Test 1 passed", else print "Test 1 failed"


How can I do the thing I want to in that comment above? Note that here I am just doing a print, but in reality I may want to do custom things in the next command based on whether the previous command passed or failed.

This is a question of the shell language, in which makefile recipes are expressed, not of make itself.  There are two components to it:

run_some_job must indicate via its exit status whether the test passed or failed.  Most natural would be to exit with status 0 on success, and with any other status (1, for example) on failure.

Use a shell conditional command to select the alternative to execute.


The latter is slightly complicated by the fact that make runs each (logical) recipe line in its own shell, but you can use semicolons (;) interchangably with newlines for most purposes in the shell language, and make provides for joining multiple physical lines into a single logical one, which serves your purposes.  For example:
test_1:
        @echo "Starting test 1"
        @if run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1; then \
          echo "Test 1 passed"; \
        else \
          echo "Test 1 failed"; \
        fi


As I was waiting for a response on this post, this is exactly what I tried as well and it works exactly how I wanted. The only additional thing I'd like to add is I also added "exit 1" in the "failed" section of the if; to make the target exit with non-zero.

I mean, that sounds exactly like what I wrote below :)

Yes @MadScientist; that's what i was about to comment in your answer :D

You have to include it in the same shell script.  Once make detects that some line in the recipe failed it will stop running the recipe, so the extra line to print "failed" will never be run.  So you have to do the check yourself, something like this:
test_1:
        @echo "Starting test 1"
        if run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1 ; then \
            print "Test 1 passed"; \
        else \
            print "Test 1 failed"; \
            exit 1; \
        fi


You don't really need to do anything explicitly. make will terminate the recipe on the first command which fails. So simply putting the command below the one which might fail causes it to be skipped if the one above it fails.
test_1:
    @echo "Starting test 1"
    run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1
    echo "Test 1 passed"

I took out the fugly @ before the main command; it makes debugging more problematic, and if you don't want to see what make is doing, you can simply use make -s.
If you want to explicitly print a failure notice in addition to the one make already prints when something fails, that gets a bit hairy:
test_1:
    @echo "Starting test 1"
    run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1 || { rc=$?; echo "Test 1 failed"; exit $$rc; }
    echo "Test 1 passed"

But again, make will print an error message when something fails, so this seems quite unnecessary.
bash$ make
Starting test 1
run_some_job > test_1.log 2>&1
make: *** [test_1] Error 1

As you can see, the error message includes the name of the target which failed, and its specific exit code.
(Circling back, it also seems unnecessary to print an explicit success indicator if you take out the @ so you can see what has been run and whether it succeeded.)
